# Resample from a sample to match a desired distribution

Tags: distributions, bias, matching, resampling

Suppose I have observations $x_1,\dots,x_n$, sampled iid from some distribution on $\mathbb{R}$, with pdf $p(x)$.  Suppose I wish I had a sample from the distribution with pdf $q(x)$.  Is there a way to select a subsample from $x_1,\dots,x_n$, so that the subsample can be treated as an iid sample from $q(x)$?

Motivation: Perhaps my observations come from a biased distribution, and I want to de-bias it.  Perhaps there has been a shift in the real-world distribution, and I watch to match the updated distribution.  Unfortunately, I can't "weight" the individual observations; all I can do is select a subset of the observations for my subsample.

In other words, I want a probabilistic process that takes $x_1,\dots,x_n$ as input, and outputs a subset of $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and such that if it is given $n$ iid draws from $p(x)$, then its output is distributed the same as some number of iid draws from $q(x)$.  Here $p(x),q(x)$ are known.  I'm glad to make any useful assumptions on $p(x),q(x)$, e.g., that they are smooth, continuously differentiable, etc.

Comment: You can use whatever technique you would use to get importance weights $w(x)=q(x)/p(x)$ and use those to draw a sample with replacement and sample weights from your original dataset? E.g. `q_sample = x_df.sample(n=10000, replace=True, weights=w_x)` in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)?

Comment: Generalize the method given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/572832/919.  First, though, please clarify your question. (1) How large should the subsample be?  (2) Do you wish to sample with or without replacement?  (3) What properties of the target distribution are important to represent in the subsample?  (For instance, if for later analysis you will rely on there being no chance of ties in a sample from a continuous distribution, then subsampling with replacement wouldn't be a viable option.)

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your response, and for the link - that is good stuff!  (1) I don't have something specific in mind.  The larger, the better, I suppose.  (2) with replacement (iid).  (3) I have no specific properties or goals of that sort.

Comment: @EikeP., Oh, gosh, what a clean solution.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assign observations a weight according to the likelihood ratio of $q(x)$ to $p(x)$ and sample according to those weights.

For instance, suppose I obtain my first sample $X$ as standard normal *but* I want to subsample $X^*$ so that it has a normal distribution with mean 2 and sd 1, each observation $x$ will be weighted according $\phi(x-2)/\phi(x)$. So for instance, the value 0 which is the mean/median/mode of the reference sample but is 2 sds from the center in the target sample has a weight of 0.16 whereas the value of 2 has a weight of 7.38.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1000)
pxq <- dnorm(x, 2, 1) / dnorm(x, 0, 1)
xstar <- sample(x, size=1000, replace=T, prob = pxq)

plot(density(x), ylim=c(0,1), xlab='X', ylab='f_x', main='Kernal density smoothed estimate')
lines(density(xstar), col='blue')
legend('topleft', col=c('black', 'blue'),lty=1, c('X', 'Xstar'))
```

[image]